# Eyes determine power manga

Tags: story-identification, manga

In the beginning of the story the Main character wakes up from what I believe is a tomb. In this world people have different colored eyes depending on the believe their attributes. Before the Main character went to sleep Golden eyes which the main character has are considered demon eyes because the demons had those color eyes and could control magic better. However, after he comes out of his slumber the golden eyes are seen as the weakest of all the colored eyes.

Also a Demon girl that he rescued before going to sleep has been waiting for him all this time to wake up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Rettougan no Tensei Majutsushi: Shiitagerareta Motoyuusha wa Mirai no Sekai wo Yoyuu de Ikinuku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119997/Rettougan_no_Tensei_Majutsushi__Shiitagerareta_Motoyuusha_wa_Mirai_no_Sekai_wo_Yoyuu_de_Ikinuku) (The Reincarnation Magician of the Inferior Eyes).

> Abel was a genius magician who held immense power in a world where the color of your eyes indicates how powerful you are. However, **the strength that came with his amber eyes was so great, even his comrades looked at him with fear and contempt.** He therefore decided to transfer his soul far into the future, hoping to find a paradise that accepts him. He would soon find out that people’s attitude regarding his eye color did change, but not quite the way he had imagined...
>
> [image]